# Setting class and value in simple form (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple form in my Rails application, i tried to set value and class to a specific input field just like below

`<%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :value => "Email", :class => "myclass" %>`

**Html output :**

[image]

but i could not able to see value and class set in the actual html form.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you paste the HTML output you get from this call?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not using the [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/) plugin for Rails, but as the documentation says you should use the `:input_html` attribute for this.

Do the following:

```
<%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, input_html: { :value => "Email", class: "myclass" } %>
```